# How to deploy a VSTO and wrap some exe tools in it?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, vsto

First of all, sorry for the vague (if not incorrect) title of this question, but noob as I am, I can't think of other way to phrasing this correctly..

More clearly, I'd like to deploy an Excel addin, developed with VS. For this, I followed Microsoft's guide for [deploying using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019#ApplySecurity). It worked fine, except for one thing: my addin is supposed to call PuTTY at some point, and the deployment as such apparently doesn't ship PuTTY (the only thing I did so far is to put PuTTY in the Solution Explorer of my project, but I guess that's not enough ;) ).

When I debug on my computer, well I have PuTTY installed, and the path to it is hardcoded, so that everything run fine. But when I deploy it (following the guide), PuTTY is missing.

How can I:

1. Ship PuTTY with my addin?
2. Foresee the location of PuTTY once deployed, and therefore being able to call it correctly?

...using the installer, not click Once.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

To whomever it may be useful, on top of Eugene's answer, what was missing is that I needed to add the Content files to my project output.
To do that, right-click on your Setup project and Add...> Project Output...> Content Files.

[image]

Then, when building the solution and deploying it, PuTTY was actually copied to the installation folder of the client!

Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

Set up properties on the file attached to the solution, basically you need to make sure the file is included to the solution output:

1. Set the `Build Action` property to `Content`.
2. Set the `Copy to the Output Directory` property to `Copy Always`.

For example, if the file is added to the project and you select it in the Solution Explorer and go to the Properties window you may see the following:

[image]

It will be added automatically to the output folder along with other add-in files. So, you will just have to rebuild the installer based on your output.

See [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Comment: Hello, thanks! So I did that, but I still don't see any "putty.exe" on the user's computer after doing this and installing. Is it supposed to be copied as such near the dll and manifest files when installing, or is it "hidden" somewhere else? Thanks again!

Comment: How did you set up your MSI installer? Did you include separate files or the output from the add-in project?

Comment: Hello, so the guide I actually followed is the one entitled "Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for Office Solution Using Windows Installer", which is different from the link you mention in your answer, entitled "Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer". How they differ, and which should I follow, I have no idea. Anyway, in the guide I followed, there is a section named "To add the ExcelAddIn project output", that I followed exactly, so I only added the "primary output" there. Is it what you are referring to? Should I also add other stuff at that point? (content files?) Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, if you include the primary output, the file should be included in the installer. Anyway, you can add the file manually.

Comment: How? :D Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you use Wix, InstallShield, MSI add-in for VS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215312/discussion-between-arnaud-and-eugene-astafiev).

Answer (score 0):

You really need to add that that utility to you installer project.
Or you can embed the utility as a resource in your dll, extract it at run-time, copy to some folder, and execute.

Comment: I have no preference. What I want is that is is basically seemless for the end user. What would a "pro" do? Also, if the end user has to/can choose the directory to put that exe, then how can I hardcode its path in my solution code? (but maybe that's not what you mean?) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Including the exe in your installer in the  right thing to do. But if you don't know how and don't have time to learn, you can include the exe as a resource. At run time, extract it into a directory of your choice (e.g. a subfolder of the AppData folder - use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`. Since you know where the exe is extracted to, you know the full path, there is no reason to hardcode anything.